# Should experienced users let newbies answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, users

I have been facing here repeatedly a kind of behaviour that has nothing to do with gentlemanliness but only pure (maybe unaware) greediness.

Let's have a situation when a newbie (reputation < 15) asks for a question that is easily answered. In most cases the correct answers or solutions are based on spotting a syntax error, a knowledge of few elementary commands or helping with Boolean logic.

It often happens, that such a question receives several similar answers (all correct). However, answers have a wide range of reputation. I subconsciously sort them into three basic categories:

- Beginners: 1 - 1000 reputation (often called newbies)
- Experienced: 1001 - 4000 reputation
- Masters: 4001 +

---

Let me continue with this categorisation based on reputation: I often see while trying to answer as a newbie that a master user with thousands of reputation answers too. It makes his answer move to the top and is very easily spotted by the original poster (OP as you say here).

It's clearly unfair that his answer is marked as correct and upvoted, although other answers are correct as well with the only difference being reputation.

Here is an example: [How to resolve Oracle missing expression in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824269/how-to-resolve-oracle-missing-expression-in-jsp) (I have to apologise to the participants of the question that I have used them as the example of this behaviour.)

You can clearly see that the master user's answer was upvoted and marked as the correct one despite the fact the newbie below answered the question with the same quality and didn't receive an upvote at all.

---

So, this is my question:

**Should experienced users let newbies answer first a very easy question?**

It's a thing of good manners, chivalry and gentlemanliness. Also it would help newbies to gain reputation and self-confidence. It has often happened me that I answered and a master user gave me a comment helping me to improve my answer or edited it himself instead of posting the new answer that is 99% sure to be upvoted.

**Or it's better to post an answer no matters newbies for out benefit?**

It's a quite selfish way to farm reputation easily. However I might feel differently if my reputation was more than 100k.

---

No, I am not crying about my problems. I'm trying to introduce you to the world of the beginning users here.

In my opinion nowadays they have easier start to the programming because of the huge database of questions and answers.

On the other hand, they have much harder chance to gain a bigger amount of reputation, because all elementary questions (syntax, comparing strings, arrays, ...) have been asked and answered a long time ago and those users have very high reputation.

Now when a newbie asks a similar question, it's downvoted and marked as a duplicate. Generally it's pretty hard to ask an original question. It's a bit off this off-topic though and maybe it deserves another topic itself.

---

Thank you for your attention and I welcome all constructive opinions and answers.

Comment: An answer is an answer. The user posting it is irrelevant. Questions that get five or six answers in a short time frame are usually trivial, and also usually either too localised to be of any use to future users, based on typos (and so should be closed), or duplicates that people answer for rep rather than close.

Comment: *"It makes his answer move to the top and is very easily spotted by the original poster"* Wait, no it doesn't. We don't sort answers by reputation of the poster. They are sorted by votes (aka usefulness). Now, it commonly happens that experienced answerers post better, more useful answers, but it is not *necessarily* the case.

Comment: To be honest the high-rep answer is slightly better but only for mentioning using a preparedstatement. The best answer, yet to be posted, should be the one that actually uses a preparedstatement ....

Comment: For your specific example, the "master" answer was posted half an hour earlier. It was "accepted" ten minutes before the "newbie" posted. It's unclear why you think user rep is relevant to which answer is upvoted / accepted.

Comment: An answer to a trite question is not often distinguished by technical accuracy.  It also matters a lot of *exactly* how you phrase the answer.  Effective communication is very, very important at SO.  A skill that a high rep user often possesses, inevitably, somebody like Jon Skeet is very good at it.  Oddly, many users don't even use such a basic tool as a spell checker.  Maybe you can explain why you don't either, ought to provide some insight why users get this wrong.

Comment: How would more experienced users know that if they see a new question that a) newbies will answer at all or b) that if they did their answer would be correct? People here see a question come up and answer it and everyone is equally entitled to do that.

Comment: Blocking those users who are *more* likely to provide quality answers from answering is a terrible idea. Perhaps there should be consequences for  users gaining a lot of rep through excessively answering trivial questions - but not a set of rules that is bound to make the site worse.

Comment: *I subconsciously sort them into three basic categories: Beginners: 1 - 1000 reputation, Experienced: 1001 - 4000 reputation, Masters: 4001 +* - This is incorrect. Reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you. Note that you get rep from questions and edits (under 2K) as well as answers. Furthermore, no one is an expert in everything. If a user who got 5K+ rep answering C questions posts an answer to an ArcGIS question, do you just assume they're an expert in that as well?

Comment: *"Masters: 4001+"* I guess that makes @pekka a "transcendental badass".

Answer (score 19):

I don't believe it matters.
You state in your example that the answer from the "Master" was moved to the top because he was the one with the highest reputation.

The reason he had his answer at the top was at first because of the fact he answered first, giving him priority over any answers with the same votes, his answer was well given and useful to the user who posted the question-

And as such, was voted up *by the user*, accepted *by the user*, and so favored not by the system, but *by the user*.

Reputation doesn't matter to me, honestly, I have a question, I want it answered, a "Master" in the sense that he gives a good answer would be infinitely more useful than a "Newbie" in the sense he doesn't know what he's talking about.

In terms of the community, a master is someone who has spent time in the community, while a newbie is new. A newbie could be better at coding than a master, for example

If a newbie has a good answer, they can answer first, and get reputation. I'm a newbie! My answer on SO has been accepted several times! If this answer gets upvotes, your point is clearly shown to be moot.

**TL;DR, If they know the answer, let them answer.**